# lifetime not long enough rust

Tags: memory-management, rust, lifetime

I want to open a file, replace some characters, and make some splits. Then I want to return the list of strings. however I get `error: broken does not live long enough`. My code works when it is in main, so it is only an issue with lifetimes.

```
fn tokenize<'r>(fp: &'r str) -> Vec<&'r str> {
    let data = match File::open(&Path::new(fp)).read_to_string(){
        Ok(n) => n,
        Err(e) => fail!("couldn't read file: {}", e.desc)
    };
    let broken = data.replace("'", " ' ").replace("\"", " \" ").replace("  ", " ");
    let mut tokens = vec![];

    for t in broken.as_slice().split_str(" ").filter(|&x| *x != "\n"){
        tokens.push(t)
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

How can I make the value returned by this function live in the scope of the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your function signature says "the result has the same lifetime as the input `fp`", but that's simply not true.  The result contains references to `data`, which is allocated inside your function; it has nothing to do with `fp`!  As it stands, `data` will cease to exist at the end of your function.

Because you're effectively creating new values, you can't return references; you need to transfer ownership of that data out of the function.  There are two ways I can think of to do this, off the top of my head:

1. Instead of returning `Vec<&str>`, return `Vec<String>`, where each token is a freshly-allocated string.
2. Return `data` inside a wrapper type which implements the splitting logic.  Then, you can have `fn get_tokens(&self) -> Vec<&str>`; the lifetime of the slices can be tied to the lifetime of the object which contains `data`.

Comment: Why does the conversion to String increase their lifetime? Are they owned by the container?

Comment: Pretty much.  `Vec` and `String` are owning containers.  When you pass one of those around, you are actually transferring ownership of the memory that's been allocated to hold their value.  `&str` is simply a *borrowed* reference; it can only live as long as the thing it's borrowed from.